# Angular lazyloading component without routing - No value accessor for form control name

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading, angular-components

I'm trying to lazyload a component without routing.
I have two components with each formGroup for a component.

`formGroup` at the parent component named `vehicleForm` including `FormControl` named `vehicleDetail`

`formGroup` at the child component including `fuel`, `model`.

Now at `vehicle.component.html` I add `formControlName='vehicleDetail'` on `<ng-template>` (where child component loaded into) to get the nested value of the child form, I've got this issue :

`No value accessor for form control name: 'vehicleDetail'`

`No value accessor for form control name: 'fuel'`

`No value accessor for form control name: 'model'`

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
// vehicle.component.ts (This is Parent component)

export class VehicleComponent implements OnInit {
  public vehicleForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    vehicleDetail: new FormControl('')
  });
  
  @ViewChild("vehicleDetailLazyLoadComponent", {read: ViewContainerRef}) vehicleDetailLazyLoadComponent!: ViewContainerRef;
  
  constructor(private injector: Injector){}
  
  ngOnInit(){}
  
  openVehicleDetail() {
    this.loadVehicleDetailComp();
  }
  
  async loadVehicleDetailComp(){
    const {VehicleDetailModule, VehicleDetailComponent} = await import("./vehicle-detail.component.ts");
    const moduleRef = createNgModule(VehicleDetailModule, this.injector)
    this.vehicleDetailLazyLoadComponent.clear();
    const {instance} = this.vehicleDetailLazyLoadComponent.createComponent(VehicleDetailComponent, {ngModuleRef: moduleRef});
  }
}
```

```html
//vehicle.component.html (This is Parent Component)

<form [formGroup]="vehicleForm">
  <button (click)="openVehicleDetail()">Click</button>
  
  <ng-template #vehicleDetailLazyLoadComponent formControlName="vehicleDetail"></ng-template>
</form>
```

```js
// vehicleDetail.component.ts (This is Child component)
@Component({
  selector: 'app-vehicle-detail',
  templateUrl: './vehicle-detail.component.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => VehicleDetailComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => VehicleDetailComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})

export class VehicleDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  form: formGroup;
  
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
  }
  
  ngOnInit(){
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      model: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      fuel: new FormControl('')
    })
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [VehicleDetailComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgSelectModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [VehicleDetailComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})

export class VehicleDetailModule {
  constructor() {}
}
```

```html
// vehicleDetail.component.html (This is Child component)
<form [formGroup]="form">
  Model: <input formControlName="model" />
  Fuel: <input formControlName="fuel" />
</form>
```

Is that this issue occured because can't add `formControlName="vehicleDetail"` on `<app-vehicle-detail></app-vehicle-detail>` when render in DOM tree ?
Does someone know how I can fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I created a working example on StackBlitz. It lazy-loads a single (standalone) component using a dynamic import and it sets the nested part of the parent's form as an input. See here:
[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-eh92wn?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

---

Old answer - direct feedback to the provided code snippets:
There are several problems here. The 1st one which is directly related to the error you see on the console is: In vehicleDetail.component.ts you create the FormGroup too late. When ngOnInit is executed, the template is already rendered. So angular already tried to find a formControl for "model" - but it has not been created yet. You can either solve that by putting form initialization into the constructor, or by adding an *ngIf="form" in the template on the form element.

Other problems I see here:

- NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR is not needed here. You only need that if you want to build your own form control (e.g. like your own autocomplete), which directly works with formControlName as a parameter given from outside.
- The way you tried to insert the child component into the parent form won't work. Instead, you can just use your child component as an element (by using e.g. ). You can define the whole formGroup structure inside of the parent component and can insert the details part of it into the child component by using input binding.

There are also some other things, but it would be too much to list it all here. Have you even used the cli in order to create this code? I'm asking because even the file names done fit the naming convention.

Maybe you should first setup it in a more easy way - e.g. without lazy loading. And as soon as it works you could add lady loading.

Comment: yeah, my requirement is make component can lazyload without using routing, so I need to implement this way, but i can't bind the formControlName for a child component. If requirement is not lazyload component, I still can pass formControlName for a child component as usual.

Comment: I have followed this blog but in this blog, these not mention about how to pass formControlName to child component.
https://www.wittyprogramming.dev/articles/lazy-load-component-angular-without-routing/

Comment: @Dwayne123, I had a look at the blog post you mentioned and I can confirm that the process of lazy loading of components, like it is described there, is working. But in that example, there are no nested forms. So I think, you problem is not about lazy loading, but about some Angular basics. The component templates are isolated. You can't just reference something from outside. Therefore, if you defined a from on the parent component, you can't just you formControlNam in the child component. You need to insert the fromGroup using input binding.

Comment: @Dwayne123, I created a working stackblitz example. I addd the link to my answer. If this is helpful, please except my answer.